# Finding Horizontal Tangents of a Graph of $f$

Tags: calculus

Find all the points on the graph of $f(x)=-x^3 +3x^2-2$ where there is a horizontal tangent line.

I got $(0,-2)$, $(2,2)$ but I'm not sure if this is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the first derivative of the function gives $f'(x)=-3x^2+6x$.

Factor out $-3x$ to get $f'(x)=-3x(x-2)$.

Set $f'(x)=0$ and solve to get $x=0$ and $x=2$.

Plug these $x$ values into $f(x)$ to get $f(0)=-2$ and $f(2)=2$.

So you get $(0,-2)$ and $(2,2)$.

Your answer was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Solve the equation
$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = 0$$
for $x$.